# How to justify that $d_{\mid\cdot\mid} ^{\alpha} (x,y) = |x-y|^{\alpha}$ (with $0<\alpha <1$) is a distance on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, inequality

I know directly that :

- $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $d_{\mid\cdot\mid}^\alpha (x,y)=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x=y$
- $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $d_{\mid\cdot\mid}^\alpha (y,x) = d_{\mid\cdot\mid}^\alpha (x,y)$
- $\forall x,z,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $d_{\mid\cdot\mid}^\alpha (x,y) = |x-y|^\alpha = |x-z+z-y|^\alpha$ $\le$ $|x-z|^\alpha+|z-y|^\alpha$ $ = d_{\mid\cdot\mid}^\alpha (x,z)+d_{\mid\cdot\mid}^\alpha (z,y) $ because $0<\alpha <1$

Is it right for the triangle inequality ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be ok.

Comment: @JohnZHANG Well, I thought I made the triangle inequality too quickly. I don't know if sayin that $\alpha \in ]0,1[$ is enough. What do you think ?

Comment: The triangle inequality is a statement about $\alpha = 1$, just writing $|x-y|^\alpha \leq |x-z|^\alpha + |z-y|^\alpha$ is not a valid solution. You need to explicitly prove that it holds for $\alpha \not= 1$ (which is the whole point of this exercise).

Comment: @Winther By definition $\mid x-y \mid \le \mid x-z \mid + \mid z-y \mid$. We know that $\mid x-y \mid \ge 0$ and $\alpha \in ]0,1[$ then by increasing $\mid x-y \mid^{\alpha} \le (\mid x-z \mid + \mid z-y \mid)^{\alpha}$. Now why could we say that : $(\mid x-z \mid + \mid z-y \mid)^{\alpha} \le \mid x-z \mid^{\alpha} + \mid z-y \mid^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha \in ]0,1[$ ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because it is not a valid argument (you cannot just say that $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$ implies $|a+b|^\alpha \leq |a|^\alpha + |b|^\alpha$ which is what you have done), you have to explicitly show that the statement is true. See the answer below for how you can show this.

Comment: @Winther In the last inequality, I divided the right member by $(\mid x-z \mid + \mid z-y \mid)^{\alpha} $ and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $\alpha\in(0,1),x,y\geq 0$, then $(x+y)^\alpha\leq x^\alpha+y^\alpha\iff (x+y)\leq (x^\alpha+y^\alpha)^\frac{1}{^\alpha}$, which is true by [generalized binomial theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem). So your last step holds.